# watir, cucumber, select a variable with string without using a case/when

Tags: cucumber, watir

I have a cucumber step like this (it is not working, but it is a concept):

```
And (/^I navigate to this url '(.*?)'$/) do |web|
   web = $ + 'web' + '_url'
   @browser.goto web
end
```

In a different file, paths.rb, I have this hardcoded URL:

```
$google_url = http://www.google.com
```

I want to be able to select that URL, by doing something like this:

```
And I navigate to this url 'google'
```

Right now, I have not find a way of selecting the 'real content' of the variable $google_url. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution - Using eval (bad idea)**

The quickest and most direct solution is to use `eval` to execute the string to get the variable. However, it is often suggested that `eval` is a bad idea.

```
And (/^I navigate to this url '(.*?)'$/) do |web|
   url = eval('$' + web + '_url')
   @browser.goto url
end
```

**Solution - Create a module and use send**

I think a better idea would be to create a module that includes all your path constants. This would be better because (1) you prevent polluting the space with many global variables and (2) using `send` is safer than `eval`.

In your paths.rb, you could replace your global variables with a module that can return the different urls:

```
module Paths
    class << self
        def google_url()
            'http://www.google.com'
        end
    end
end
```

You would then use `send` in your steps to translate the string to a method:

```
And (/^I navigate to this url '(.*?)'$/) do |web|
   url = Paths.send(web + '_url')
   @browser.goto url
end
```

Comment: I like the 'eval' aprox. is what I was looking for.